# How to set up localization on react-big-calendar using momentjs

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

https://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html

I am trying to implement something similar to the above example but with momentjs instead of globalizer.

So how to import the timezones I need from momentjs and use it in my calendar so that user can choose the timezone and language

edit:

here's my code it's pretty basic for now

```
const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment)
const DragAndDropCalendar = withDragAndDrop(Calendar)
const cultures = ['en', 'en-GB', 'es', 'fr', 'ar-AE']

<DragAndDropCalendar
        selectable
        localizer={localizer}
        events={schedule}
        className="cal_height"
        style={{ height: 1550 }}
        onSelectSlot={(e) => handlecreateSchedule(e)}
        onSelectEvent={(e) => handleselectSchedule(e)}
        onEventDrop={handleupdateSchedule}
        defaultView="week"
        min={new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), 8)}
        scrollToTime={moment().set({ h: 10, m: 0 }).toDate()}
        timeslots={2}
        step={15}
        popup
        tooltipAccessor={(e) => e.title}
        startAccessor="start"
        endAccessor="end"
        components={{
          event: EventComponent,
        }}
        culture={cultures}
      />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You setup localization correctly, though your localizer would first require setting a default timezone. First, you'd have to be using [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/). By default it uses your user's default (browser local) timezone. To change that, you can reset the default timezone used by moment.

```js
moment.tz.setDefault(String);
```

Your bigger problem is that, currently, React-Big-Calendar does not completely support timezone switching. This is largely due to it, internally, using the `date-fns` library when creating it's timeslots, as opposed to using localizer methods. This is laid out in [this issue](https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar/issues/1478).

**FINAL EDIT:** The (0.36.0) latest version of RBC has full timezone support now, when using either the `momentLocalizer` or the new `luxonLocalizer`. Doc site isn't up to date yet, but if you run the 'examples' locally you'll find all the info.

Comment: Thank you for the information it helps! I have actually switched to fullcalendar now because I really needed the timezone switching.